# Getting the window height with overflow=hidden in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a full screen web application that should never scroll, so I set:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

However, when I add a resize listener:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("Inner height: " + $(window).innerHeight());
    console.log("Height: " + $(window).height());
    console.log("Document: " + $(document).height());
    console.log("Body: " + $("body").height());
});
```

The height is reported correctly when I make the window *taller* but it's incorrect when I make it smaller. In fact, the window height (through any of those variables) *only* increases (correctly if I make it bigger, and a little bit if I make it smaller).

The content, in case it's relevant, is an html `<video>` element that takes the whole window space on ready.

I have read that height() won't work in overflow: hidden, but I couldn't get a reason why not. Also, how on earth do I get the correct height? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try setting

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hey, that worked! I now do `$("body").height("100%") before reading out the values, and it's solved the problem. I don't quite understand the why, though. $(window).height is supposed to report the viewport size, which ought to be independent of the body size... Any ideas? And thanks a bunch!

Comment: well no. Actually a good guess ;) But you are right, window.height should always give the dimensions of the window, no matter what happens with css

Comment: Great :) Well, since that makes two of us that don't know the reason, I'll see if this progresses as a bug report. I'll keep you posted, and thanks!